# How hook __thiscall function in c++

Tags: c++, assembly, hook, reverse-engineering

I have hooked correctly many games using detours without problems but now I have a problem with this __thiscall function:

```
.text:00488DA0 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:00488DA0
.text:00488DA0 ; Attributes: bp-based frame
.text:00488DA0
.text:00488DA0 ; int __stdcall sub_488DA0(int, int, int, char, int, float, float, float, int)
.text:00488DA0 sub_488DA0      proc near               ; CODE XREF: sub_4853C0+53↑p
.text:00488DA0                                         ; sub_489270+43↓p ...
.text:00488DA0
.text:00488DA0 var_8           = dword ptr -8
.text:00488DA0 var_4           = dword ptr -4
.text:00488DA0 arg_0           = dword ptr  8
.text:00488DA0 arg_4           = dword ptr  0Ch
.text:00488DA0 arg_8           = dword ptr  10h
.text:00488DA0 arg_C           = byte ptr  14h
.text:00488DA0 arg_10          = dword ptr  18h
.text:00488DA0 arg_14          = dword ptr  1Ch
.text:00488DA0 arg_18          = dword ptr  20h
.text:00488DA0 arg_1C          = dword ptr  24h
.text:00488DA0 arg_20          = dword ptr  28h
.text:00488DA0
.text:00488DA0                 push    ebp
.text:00488DA1                 mov     ebp, esp
.text:00488DA3                 sub     esp, 8
.text:00488DA6                 push    ebx
.text:00488DA7                 mov     ebx, dword ptr [ebp+arg_C]
.text:00488DAA                 push    esi
.text:00488DAB                 mov     esi, ecx
.text:00488DAD                 mov     [ebp+var_4], esi
.text:00488DB0                 cmp     ebx, 0FFFFFFFFh
.text:00488DB3                 jl      short loc_488DBD
.text:00488DB5                 cmp     ebx, 400h
.text:00488DBB                 jl      short loc_488DD9
.text:00488DBD
.text:00488DBD loc_488DBD:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_488DA0+13↑j
.text:00488DBD                 cmp     [ebp+arg_10], 7
.text:00488DC1                 jz      short loc_488DD9
.text:00488DC3                 push    ebx             ; char
.text:00488DC4                 push    offset a1startsoundBad ; "^1StartSound: bad edictnum %i"
.text:00488DC9                 call    sub_426A40
.text:00488DCE                 add     esp, 8
.text:00488DD1                 pop     esi
.text:00488DD2                 pop     ebx
.text:00488DD3                 mov     esp, ebp
.text:00488DD5                 pop     ebp
.text:00488DD6                 retn    24h
.text:00488DD9 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

.text:00488E22 etc.....

.text:00489261 loc_489261:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_488DA0+BA↑j
.text:00489261                                         ; sub_488DA0+D5↑j ...
.text:00489261                 pop     edi
.text:00489262                 pop     esi
.text:00489263                 pop     ebx
.text:00489264                 mov     esp, ebp
.text:00489266                 pop     ebp
.text:00489267                 retn    24h
.text:00489267 sub_488DA0      endp
```

here IDA pseudocode:

```
void __thiscall sub_488DA0(char *this, int a2, int a3, int a4, int a5, int a6, float a7, float a8, float a9, int a10)
```

here my code:

```
typedef void(__fastcall *HookFileWolfram) (char * pThis, void * EDX, int a2, int a3, int a4, int a5, int a6, float a7, float a8, float a9, int a10);
void  __fastcall HookWeaponFileSubWolfram(char * pThis, void * EDX, int a2, int a3, int a4, int a5, int a6, float a7, float a8, float a9, int a10)
{
    HookFileWolfram originalFunction = (HookFileWolfram)AddressOfHookSoundFunction;

    LF::Log_Update("Print values: pThis: " + SC::To_String(pThis) + " a2: " + SC::To_String(a2));

    return originalFunction(pThis,EDX,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10);
}
```

and here the output:

```
  18/07/2022 08:32:43.860  Print values: pThis: 2O/ a2: 1143863296
  18/07/2022 08:32:42.420  Print values: pThis: G/ a2: 0
```

I need to detect correctly the parameter pThis.

Can you please let me known a way to detect the pThis parameter ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

signature of hook function must be **exactly** match with original function signature. the `__thiscall` and `__fastcall` is different calling conventions for *x86* - second parameter in case `__fastcall` inside `edx` when in case `__thiscall` in stack and so on.

for instance you want hook `AAA::Func` function :

```
struct AAA 
{
    ULONG _a = 0;

    ULONG Func(void* p1, int p2, double f)
    {
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>(%p, %x, %d)\n", __FUNCTION__, this, p1, p2, (int)(f*100));
        return ++_a;
    }
};
```

you need declare hook function also as class member with match signature:

```
struct HHH
{
    inline static ULONG (HHH::*originalFunction)(void* p1, int p2, double f);
    
    ULONG Hook(void* p1, int p2, double f)
    {
        ULONG r = (this->*originalFunction)(p1, p2, f);
        DbgPrint("%s:\tAAA::Func<%p>(%p, %x)=%x\n", __FUNCTION__, this, p1, p2, r);
        return r;
    }
};
```

and example of hook/unhook

```
AAA a;

union {
    PVOID pv;
    ULONG (AAA::*pfn)(void* , int , double );
    ULONG (HHH::*phn)(void* , int , double );
};

phn = &HHH::Hook;

// implementation is not important
T_HOOK_ENTRY hook = { 
    0, 
    pv /* = &HHH::Hook */, 
    (void**)&HHH::originalFunction
};

pfn = &AAA::Func;

// implementation is not important
TrHook(pv /* = &AAA::Func */, &hook);

a.Func(&__ImageBase, 8, 0.54);
a.Func(&__ImageBase, 8, -0.37);

TrUnHook(&hook);

a.Func(&__ImageBase, 8, 0.63);
```

i use my own implementation, but any detour implementation take 3 params:

- address of function to hook ( `&AAA::Func` )
- address of hook function ( `&HHH::Hook` )
- address where save new function begin ( `&HHH::originalFunction`)

in your case this is `sub_488DA0`, `HookWeaponFileSubWolfram and AddressOfHookSoundFunction`

from own test i got next output

```
AAA::Func<0055FCE4>(007F0000, 8, 54)
HHH::Hook:  AAA::Func<0055FCE4>(007F0000, 8)=1
AAA::Func<0055FCE4>(007F0000, 8, -37)
HHH::Hook:  AAA::Func<0055FCE4>(007F0000, 8)=2
AAA::Func<0055FCE4>(007F0000, 8, 63)
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. There is a more simple way to get the value only first parameter "char *this" ? I admit that I am not very expert.

Comment: you can use asm code for the hook, and here you can do any. also what is *more simply way* is very relative. i not view nothing complex in posted way

Comment: yes, for what I remembrer is possible use: "_declspec(naked)" and inside the assembly code inside. But I don't known how I can use it to detect the first pamemter.